# Android: reusing a customadapter when dealing with multiple layouts

Tags: android, listview, layout, adapter

i'm quite new to app developing and I am wondering about some good design patterns  when it comes to adapters for ListViews.

I don't have any specific code (at least not simple and clear code) to accompany the question, but anyway, here is the situation.

I have an Activity in which I want to show any List of Books.
I made a CustomAdapter for this, based on layout called "row.xml." This xml includes a TextView and an ImageView. 
I create my CustomAdapter in this Activity as follows:

`customAdapter = new ListAdapterFullList(this, R.layout.row, bookList.getList());`

Now i want to reuse this Activity to show a List of Books, but the layout needs to be different this time! It should be "row_alt.xml". Instead of a TextView and an ImageView, this list now needs to display a TextView and a RatingBar.

The problem that i am facing here is that obviously I want to reuse the Activity (since what i need to display is still a List of Books and all the other behaviour is the same), but I don't know how to handle the adapter. I can't just use this:

`customAdapter = new ListAdapterFullList(this, R.layout.row_alt, bookList.getList());`

because this ListAdapterFullList is not implemented to handle a RatingBar instead of an ImageView.

How can i bypass this problem? Do I need to create a different Adapter to show this layout? If so, then I will need to modify my existing Activity also, although I do not know how.

Btw, I read a lot about problems where different layouts need to be used for each row in a ListView, but this is not what I am struggling with. I want to reuse an adapter with a completely different layout for the Adapter. The rows themselves are always the same.

Thanks for the help, and apologies for the possible confusing question. You can always ask for more info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If row.xml and row_alt.xml only have two different widget, I suggest that you create two different Adapter. If really there is a common behavior between this two Adapters, create a parent class that will implements the common behavior and make your two adapter extends this parent class. Then each Adapter implements its own [getView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)) method.

Then for further optimizations use the [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) Pattern.

I also suggest that you take a look at [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) which is the new version of ListView and don't need the ViewHolder Pattern